# Conditional regex to preserve matching case

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find the correct syntax for a conditional regex. I've found this other question, but it doesn't seem to work on PHP. Basically, I have the words:

```
meva, meves, teva, teves, seva, seves
```

The can arrive in all the possible case variants (MEVA, Meva, meVa...). I want to create a regular expression that replaces the 'v' by a 'u', always respecting the 'v' case. To detect that I use:

```
(\b|_)(me|te|se)(?:(V)|(v))(a|es)(\b)
```

This part seems to work fine. But when I have to create the expression that replaces the v (meva -> meua, Meva -> Meua, meVa -> meUa...), I'm not able to do it correctly:

```
\1\2(\3?"V":"v")\4\5 -> doesn't work
```

Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: use `preg_replace_callback` and write `return $vMatch == 'V' ? 'U' : 'u';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$input = "meva, meves, teva, teVes, seva, seves";    
echo preg_replace_callback("/(\b|_)(me|te|se)(?:(V)|(v))(a|es)(\b)/i",
        function ($match) {
            return $match[2] . ($match[3] == "V" ? "U" : "u") . $match[5];
        },
        $input);

//output: meua, meues, teua, teUes, seua, seues
```

You may consider reordering the capturing groups:

```
(?:\b|_)(me|te|se)(V|v)(a|es)\b
```

This way the groups will be one after another in the $match-array, so you can use `$match[1]` to `$match[3]` instead of 2, 3 and 5.

[Example@ideone](http://ideone.com/atbg3s)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace_callback("/(\b|_)(m|t|s)e(v)(a|es)\b/i", function ($m) {
    return $m[1] . $m[2] . "e" . chr(ord($m[3]) - 1) . $m[3];
}, $str)
```